# Auth0 works locally with built-in macOS php dev server but not with mamp

Tags: php, authentication, mamp, auth0

I'm using Auth0's [example code](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/php) for the php sdk, which works fine when I run it from the macOS dev server (`php -S 127.0.0.1:3000 index.php`) but it doesn't work with mamp. With mamp, it doesn't go to the universal login, but instead routes to 127.0.0.1:3000/login, which doesn't exist as a page because the `login()` method is supposed to route to Auth0's universal login.

index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Import the Composer Autoloader to make the SDK classes accessible:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Load our environment variables from the .env file:
(Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__))->load();

// Now instantiate the Auth0 class with our configuration:
$auth0 = new \Auth0\SDK\Auth0([
    'domain' => $_ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN'],
    'clientId' => $_ENV['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'],
    'clientSecret' => $_ENV['AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    'cookieSecret' => $_ENV['AUTH0_COOKIE_SECRET']
]);


// Import our router library:
use Steampixel\Route;

// Define route constants:
define('ROUTE_URL_INDEX', rtrim($_ENV['AUTH0_BASE_URL'], '/'));
define('ROUTE_URL_LOGIN', ROUTE_URL_INDEX . '/login');
define('ROUTE_URL_CALLBACK', ROUTE_URL_INDEX . '/callback');
define('ROUTE_URL_LOGOUT', ROUTE_URL_INDEX . '/logout');

Route::add('/', function() use ($auth0) {
  $session = $auth0->getCredentials();

  if ($session === null) {
    // The user isn't logged in.
    include_once "landing/index.php";

  }

  // The user is logged in.
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($session->user);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo '<p>You can now <a href="/logout">log out</a>.</p>';

  include_once "app/main.php";
  
});


Route::add('/login', function() use ($auth0) {
    // It's a good idea to reset user sessions each time they go to login to avoid "invalid state" errors, should they hit network issues or other problems that interrupt a previous login process:
    $auth0->clear();

    // Finally, set up the local application session, and redirect the user to the Auth0 Universal Login Page to authenticate.
    header("Location: " . $auth0->login(ROUTE_URL_CALLBACK));
    exit;
});


Route::add('/callback', function() use ($auth0) {
    // Have the SDK complete the authentication flow:
    $auth0->exchange(ROUTE_URL_CALLBACK);

    // Finally, redirect our end user back to the / index route, to display their user profile:
    header("Location: " . ROUTE_URL_INDEX);
    exit;
});


Route::add('/logout', function() use ($auth0) {
    // Clear the user's local session with our app, then redirect them to the Auth0 logout endpoint to clear their Auth0 session.
    header("Location: " . $auth0->logout(ROUTE_URL_INDEX));
    exit;
});

// This tells our router that we've finished configuring our routes, and we're ready to begin routing incoming HTTP requests:
Route::run('/');
```

The landing page shows up as expected when the user is not logged in. But when the login button is clicked, the `login()` method is not called as is supposed to happen; instead, it redirects to 127.0.0.1:3000/login, which expectedly throws a 404 because that page doesn't exist. This error only happens with mamp. When I stop mamp and switch to the built-in macOS dev server, everything works fine.

I tried downgrading php from 8.1.9 to 8.1.0 to match the latest php version for mamp but it still didn't work. I've been struggling with this for days and can't figure it out.

Comment: Solved! I had to enable `mod-rewrite` in mamp's apache. it was already enabled in macOS apache, which is why the routing had worked for the macOS environment, but not for mamp.